# Библиотека vk_api - проблема при авторизации

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь авторизоваться как обычно:

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(phone, password)
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```

На строке с `session.auth()` такая ошибка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0JHn.png
Запускал готовый код который раньше работал без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуй сразу вставить твои данные
2. Отключи двухфакторку

```css
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi("+77777777777", "kotiki228") 
vk_session.auth() 
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```